# External Javascript loading on Google Chrome, Not Firefox 4 (Error 400)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, firefox, google-chrome

I am working on an application in ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0 that uses external javascript that I reference from the current working page.  Namely, this is the file hierarchy from the root directory:

- js

  - jquery-1.5.min.js
- ...
- student

  - js

    - Course.js
    - Plan.js
    - (etc)
  - ...
  - plan.aspx [current working page]

In plan.aspx, in the main body of the page (outside of the header), I am make a number of calls to these javascript pages:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="..\js\jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\HTMLTrees.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\Course.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\Schedule.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\Plan.js"></script>
 ...
</asp:Content>
```

Google Chrome (11.08) and Internet Explorer 8 are able to locate the files just fine and begin the execution of the scripts.  Firefox 4 and previous versions are unable to locate the file, as each request returns an error code (400 - Bad Request).

Help me out?

Comment: Let me guess: it has something to do with backslashes

Comment: That was it.  
<script type="text/javascript" src=".\js\Plan.js"></script> 

Should be
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/Plan.js"></script>

You would think that files in Windows for file paths would be referenced in the same way when making requests to the server.  Guess I will stick to Unix file path format from now on

Comment: Then I'll write it as an answer for future generations. ;)

Comment: That's because they're not file paths, they're relative URIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox encodes backslashes in URL as `%5C`. Unless you have a fix on a server side, it won't work.

Standart dictates to use forward slashes for URLs, so I guess you should change backslashes to forward slashes in URLs.